# What is the difference between a//b and int(a/b)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

They seem to be equal for small numbers but different for larger.

For example:

```
a = int(1267650600228229401496703205376/10)
b = 1267650600228229401496703205376 // 10
print(a - b) # prints 7036874417767

a = int(1493845793475/10)
b = 1493845793475 // 10
print(a - b) # prints 0
```

How come?

Comment: `int(a/b)` is truncated towards zero.

Comment: In Python3, `a/b` will perform float division, which is inexact. Even if you cast the result to an `int`, you have already introduced inexactness.

Comment: This works only for Python 3. For Python 2 it gives 0 in both cases.

Comment: [Why float arithmetic is hard](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 `/` performs float division, which has 53 bits of precision; `//` does floor division, which has no precision limit when both operands are integers (apart from limitations imposed by available RAM).

You can get the Python 3 behaviour in Python 2 by using the `true_division` `__future__` import.

Answer (score 5):

Complementing the existing answers it seems worthwile mentioning that you needn't go that far out to observe a difference:

```
>>> -1//2
-1
>>> int(-1/2)
0
```

Comment: True, but that difference is due to a completely different factor -- that `//` uses floor division. The issue the OP was asking about is due to float imprecision.

Comment: @B.Eckles Well, I said 'complementing'; and it certainly should be part of the answer since the headline question is "What is the difference between a//b and int(a/b)?"

Comment: True dat. Point taken. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @khelwood explained, in Python 3, `a/b` performs float division. Try typing `1/2` into an interpreter -- you'll get `0.5`, not `0`.

So in your example, `1267650600228229401496703205376 / 10` in reality is equal to `126765060022822940149670320537.6 = 1.267650600228229401496703205376e+29` (floating point division), but due to the inaccuracy of floats, Python evaluates it as `1.2676506002282295e+29`, so you've lost precision, which accounts for the difference.

See [PEP 238](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator).